# Ractive two way binding with multiple values

Tags: javascript, jquery, ractivejs

I have multiple row of radio inputs. User have to select either `fixed` or `percentage` from each row. i.e

[image]

I can't find the best definition in the ractive documentation.

when my js has 
`{name: 'foo', checked: true}`

And my template has

`<input type="radio" name="{{name}}" value="fixed" checked="{{checked}}">Fixed`

I can not do that in ractive as its saying

`A radio input can have two-way binding on its name attribute, or its checked attribute - not both`

Is there any documentation anywhere you know can help me to use multiple value in in input element.

Or how can I do that in ractive?

Thanks.

Comment: `radio` inputs are used to specify which of multiple values should be assigned to one single property. Your example is confusing in that it looks more like a checkbox, one value that is either true or false. Can you expand your example to include a second data option?

Comment: Done. Uploaded the image, I think it will easier to understand.

Comment: Do you have control over the data format? If not, is it like `{ name: 'fixed', checked: true }, { name: 'percent', checked: false}`? Or is it just either `{ name: 'fixed', checked: true }` or `{ name: 'fixed', checked: false }`?

Comment: I am using the `ractive.push()`. So for each row I have `{ name: 'fixed', checked: true }` where `name` can be either `fixed` or `percentage` and `checked` can be either true/false.

Comment: What happens when you have a row like `{ name: 'fixed', checked: false }`? Are both inputs unchecked in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use two-way binding with radio inputs, Ractive will automatically check the one that has the same value as the bound variable (in your case `name`):

```
<input type="radio" name="{{day}}" value="Monday">
<input type="radio" name="{{day}}" value="Tuesday">
<input type="radio" name="{{day}}" value="Wednesday">
<input type="radio" name="{{day}}" value="Thursday">
<input type="radio" name="{{day}}" value="Friday">
<input type="radio" name="{{day}}" value="Saturday">
<input type="radio" name="{{day}}" value="Sunday">
```

```
new Ractive({
    el: 'body',
    template: '#template',
    data: {
        // Friday will be checked by default.
        day: 'Friday'
    }
});
```

Tutorial: http://learn.ractivejs.org/two-way-binding/1

Comment: This solution does not work for me, please refer to the image I just uploaded.

Comment: I actually solved it from your answer. I am reading the last radio elements :checked value and passing it as name to the next one. i.e `var name = $(".selector:checked").last().val();` and `{elementName: name}`. Thanks :). Hope to see some up-vote.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do what you want (though I'm not entirely sure about your data model):

```
<input type="radio" name="{{checked}}" value="{{ true }}">Fixed
<input type="radio" name="{{checked}}" value="{{ false }}">%
<br>
{{name}} is {{checked}}
```

where

```
data: {
    name: 'foo', checked: true
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/9jan1j7q/

Answer (score 0):

Per [@martypdx's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25914266/1037948), you only need to associate/bind the input to the property it represents, but the trick was that in order for the input value to match the property value (what [@martin-kolarik meant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25913206/1037948)) *when the value is a boolean* is that you need to wrap it with handlebars (like @martypdx did).

Granted, if you're trying to create a POST-able form (since you want the `name` to show up as the input name), this won't be correct because Ractive will name the input from the context/keypath.

Updated fiddle -- http://jsfiddle.net/drzaus/9jan1j7q/1/

### Template

```
<table>
{{#each list}}
    <tr>
        <th>{{name}}</th>
        <td>
            <label><input type="radio" name="{{checked}}" value="{{true}}">Fixed</label>
            <label><input type="radio" name="{{checked}}" value="{{false}}">%</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
{{/each}}

<pre>{{json(this)}}</pre>
```

### Ractive

```
function createEntry() {
    return { name: Math.random().toString(36), checked: Math.random() < 0.5 }
}

function createList(n) {
    var list = [];
    while(n-- >= 0) list.push(createEntry());
    return list;
}

var r = new Ractive({
    el: document.body,
    template: '#template',
    data: {
        list: createList(5)
        ,
        // debug formatting
        json: function(arg) { return JSON.stringify(arg, undefined, 4); }

    }
})
```